# preset select value in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi I have a list of information i am sending from the controller to the page which is this

```
 [creditCardList] => array(6) (
    [0] => stdClass object {
      text_code => (string) 1
      text_value => (string) Visa
    }
    [1] => stdClass object {
      text_code => (string) 2
      text_value => (string) MasterCard
    }
    [2] => stdClass object {
      text_code => (string) 3
      text_value => (string) Eurocard
    }
    [3] => stdClass object {
      text_code => (string) 4
      text_value => (string) Amex
    }
    [4] => stdClass object {
      text_code => (string) 5
      text_value => (string) Diners
    }
    [5] => stdClass object {
      text_code => (string) 6
      text_value => (string) Other
    }
  )
```

And in the html page I want to preset the value that loads is text_code 1 , which is VISA, but I cannot achieve that. Here is the html code.
I tried by writing `$creditCardList->text_code[1]` but did not work.

```
<select name="credit_card_select" id="my_profile_select_credit_card" class="form-control country_style">
                <?php
                  if(!($userriskrate['credit_card_type'] > 0)){
                    echo '<option value="' . $creditCardList->text_code[1]. '">' . $creditCard->text_value . '</option>';
                    foreach ($creditCardList as $creditCard){
                        echo '<option value="' . $creditCard->text_code. '">' . $creditCard->text_value . '</option>';
                    }
                  }else{
                    foreach ($creditCardList as $creditCard){
                        echo '<option value="' . $creditCard->text_code. '"';
                        if($creditCard->text_code == $userriskrate['credit_card_type']){
                            echo 'selected';
                        }
                        echo '>' . $creditCard->text_value .'';     
                        echo  '</option>';          
                    }
                  }
                  ?> 
                </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this as creditcard[i] as it has an array().

```
 echo '<option value="' . $creditCardList[0]->text_code. '">' . $creditCardList[0]->text_value . '</option>';
```

This will give u visa as value which is visa.

To display values other than the preselected value

```
              <?php
              if(!($userriskrate['credit_card_type'] > 0)){
                echo '<option value="' . $creditCardList[0]->text_code. '">' . $creditCard[0]->text_value . '</option>';
                 $presetvalue = $creditCardList[0]->text_code;
                foreach ($creditCardList as $creditCard){

                    if($presetvalue !== $creditCard->text_code)
                    {  
                    echo '<option value="' . $creditCard->text_code. '">' . $creditCard->text_value . '</option>';

                    }
                }  
             }
```

Comment: @Farhana sorry i wrote creditcard[0]->text_value  instead of creditcardList[0]->text_value. The text code part was correct. My bad

Comment: Thanks for the correction :D it shows it works, but now I have two Visa, since one is preseleted, and another comes in the drop down menu..any clue how to fix dat?

Comment: @Farhana sorry again made a silly mistake. check my edited ans

Answer (score 0):

your error is here : `echo '<option value="' . $creditCardList->text_code[1]. '">' . $creditCard->text_value . '</option>';`

its need to be :

```
echo '<option value="' . $creditCardList[0]->text_code. '">' . $creditCard[0]->text_value . '</option>';
```

I refactored the code here :

```
   if(!($userriskrate['credit_card_type'] > 0)) $selector = 'VISA'; else $selector = $userriskrate['credit_card_type'];
      foreach ($creditCardList as $creditCard){
            if($creditCard->text_value == $selector) $selected='SELECTED'; else $selected='';
            echo '<option value="' . $creditCard->text_code. ' '.$selected.'">' . $creditCard->text_value . '</option>';
      }
```

Comment: Hey Thanks it works!!! I am going to accept the answer, when the time limit is over, and wanted to ask one more question, if I want to restrict so it only shows visa card and master card, how can i do that?

Comment: Just add 2 lines : `$autorizedValues = array('Visa','MasterCard');` and in your loop `if(!in_array($creditCard->text_value,$autorizedValues) continue;` so when the `text_value` is not in the `$autorizedValues` records it will skip it